# Why C# TcpListener need IP address

Tags: c#

Why the class TcpListener in C# need an IP address in the constructor? As we just opening a port on the localhost and export it outside.

e.g

```
public TcpListener(IPAddress localaddr, int port)
```

The equivalent from java for example, ServerSocket class, don't have such constructor that required IP.
Only the port is required.

Comment: One reason is that your PC may often have multiple adapters (real or virtual) that it can listen on.

Comment: What if the machine has multiple IP addresses, in addition to the loopback address, and you only want to listen to one?

Comment: There was a `public TcpListener (int port);` it's obsolete since .Net 1.1 (April 2003)  because of the reason cited above. 16 years… I'm old.

Comment: Listener should always use IP address IP.Any which will listen on any network connection on machine.  Using an IP Address may not get all incoming messages if they are on different Networks.  Also if you have your client and listener on same machine using the same IP on client and listener will give an error.  So Listener should listen on IP.Any and client should send to Machine IP address so there is no conflict between client and server.

Comment: @jdweng "Always" is a hard word to use here tbh. There are many use cases where you really _do_ want to bind to a certain address instead of any of them.

Comment: Only if you want a certain subnet instead of the entire network.  In general you should not use an IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments really answered this one already – it's there so you have to be explicit about which address to bind to.

If you don't care, `IPAddress.Any` will do. If you only want local binding, `IPAddress.Loopback`.

However, to go a bit deeper regarding that `ServerSocket` you allude to, you can see [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/848614a01cedcb804e0ab57fec8376fd22cb322d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/ServerSocket.java#L131-L133) that the addressless constructor really just calls the [3-argument constructor](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/848614a01cedcb804e0ab57fec8376fd22cb322d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/ServerSocket.java#L233) with a `null` address parameter and the docs say

> If *bindAddr* is null, it will default accepting connections on any/all local addresses.

This means that Java's

```
new ServerSocket(1234)
```

is equivalent to C#'s

```cs
new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234)
```